# How do I find information on bash special parameters ($* $@ $# $? $- $$ $! $0 $_)?

Tags: bash, shell, special-characters

(I've seen a number of questions here about Bash special parameters. It can be difficult to search for things like `$*`, both in the Bash manual and via Google. This question is intended to be a general reference for these questions.)

The Bash shell defines a number of "special parameters" (which is itself a bit confusing, since most of us think of them as "variables", not "parameters"). References to them consist of a dollar sign followed by some punctuation character.

Google searches for strings consisting of punctuation characters are notoriously difficult, and there are no occurrences of, for example, `$?` in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

How can I find information on particular Bash special parameters?

Comment: Given as this was clearly created with the intent that it be a reference question, it's curious to see it closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation on Bash special parameters:

```
$* $@ $# $? $- $$ $! $0 $_
```

can be found in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/), specifically in [section 3.4.2, "Special Parameters"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html). If you have the bash documentation installed on your system, you can type

```
% info bash
```

and then search for "Special Parameters".

As rici points out in a comment, within the `info` command you can also find the special parameters via the index: type `i` and then type the single character (excluding the `$`), then Enter. This doesn't work for `?`, and searching for `!` finds a different section first (typing `,` to find the next entry works). (This still works reasonably well after I apply my patch.)

It's unfortunate, IMHO, that this section refers to these parameters *without* the leading `$` character. (I've just submitted a patch that changes this.)

A brief summary (but read the manual for details):

- `$*`: Expands to the positional parameters starting with `$1`.
- `$@`: Also expands to the positional parameters, but behaves differently when enclosed in double quotes.
- `$#`: Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.
- `$?`: Expands to the exit status of the most recent command. (Similar to `$status` in csh and tcsh.)
- `$-`: Expands to the current option flags.
- `$!`: Expands to the process ID of the most recent background command.
- `$0`: Expands to the name of the shell or script. (Note that `$0`, unlike `$1` et al, is not a positional parameter.)
- `$_`: Initially set to the absolute pathname use to invoke the shell or shell script, later set to the last argument of the previous command. (There's more; see the manual.)

**UPDATE** :

As of bash version 4.3, released 2014-02-26, the bash documentation is annotated to show the full names of these variables. In release 4.2:

```
`#'
     Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.
```

In release 4.3:

```
`#'
     ($#) Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.
```

Comment: If you have the `bash` manpage, which is probably installed by default, you can `man bash` and search for Special Parameters. If you have the `info` file installed (`bash-doc` package on some distros), you can search for the individual special character in the index, using the `i` command; eg `i*`. This works for almost all the special parameters. (`info bash '--index-search=*'` is possible but too much typing imho.)

Comment: @rici: Sure -- *if* you already know that "Special Parameters" is the term used by the manual. Personally, I tend to think of them as "variables", not "parameters". Good point about the index; I didn't know that trick.

Comment: I was just quoting your answer about searching "Special Parameters"; it's just as easy in the manpage as the info doc. One of the many idiosyncracies of `info` is that if you want the index entry (starting with) `?`, you need to type the question mark twice, because the first `?` is the 'show-completions' character, subtly different from `tab`.

Comment: Submitted a patch for bash? Could you please ensure that someone generates the online docs & updates those.

Comment: @devnull: If the patch is accepted, presumably that will happen more or less automatically. If not, I'll make the patch available for anyone who wants to apply it and build from source.

Comment: I know at least two people, including me, have submitted a patch to make special parameters searchable in man bash, but it was rejected both times :/

Comment: @thatotherguy: The change was made in release 4.3. I can't tell whether it was done in response to the patch I submitted.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's great, though I see that this is only the case for the info page, and not for the man page