# What is $? in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand a script that was written a few years ago by someone that is no longer available here. The script references `$?` a few times. What is this?

P.S. Google couldn't help since it seems to strip the `$?` from the search term

Comment: Google perfectly help "dollar shell bash" ...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20272085/827263

Answer (score 7):

You really should read the [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) manual. `$?` is a [special parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) which

> expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

Read also the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).